# Problem to execute root cause is the path on R

Tags: r

I would like to execute a script but unfortunately it does not succeed, because of the path,
the script is in the following path

```
/Users/gnonogu/Desktop/Stone/script.R
```

and the data to read is in the path below

```
/Users/gnonogu/Desktop/Stone/Dataset/activity_labels.txt
```

When I try to execute this:

```
activity_labels <-read.table ("~ /Desktop/Stone/Dataset/activity_labels.txt")
Fehler in file (file, "rt"): can not open connection
Additionally: Warning message:
In file (file, "rt"):
   kann Datei '/Users/gnonogu/Desktop/Stone/Dataset/activity_labels.txt' do not open: No such file or directory

activity_labels <-read.table("~/Desktop/Stone/Dataset/activity_labels.txt")
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If a script cannot find (follow) the path you entered then there is only one reason why - you provided a path that cannot be followed.

The path you provided appears to be wrong - unless your r working directory is also the desktop. And that would be very unusual.  The tilde is used to access files that are located in the same folder as the r working directory.

Try getting rid of the tilde and replace with:

`c:\desktop\..\..etc`

Comment: This looks like a Windows path formatting. The OP's looks more like a macOS path formatting. The part you've posted isn't interchangeable between OSes

Comment: i wooking with MacOS